# How do I access the array using the for loop in the while loop

Tags: python

I am working with an external file which has data in the form of:

-12345 CSEE 35000 Bart Simpson

-12346 CSEE 25000 Harry Potter

-12350 Economics 30000 Krusty The Clown

-13123 Economics 55000 David Cameron

With the first item being the ID, the second the subject, the third the salary, and the rest being the name of the person.

In part of my program I am trying to print the information of the people who have salaries between values submitted by the user. I have put all the data in a list called lecturers then I put all the salaries in a separate list called lecturers salary and tried to make them integers because at first I thought the reason the for loop wasn't working was because when trying to access them from the lectures loop I thought they might still be part of a string at this point.

I have already used a loop in my program to print all the people who teach a specific subject. This subject is submitted by the user. I tried to use a for loop again for the salaries but its not working.

```
print""

# To God be the Glory

lecturer = []
lecturer_salary = []

x = 0
a = " "

print ""
String = raw_input("Please enter the lecturers details: ")
print ""

def printFormat(String):
    String = String.split()
    lastname = String[-1]
    firstnames = " ".join(String[3:-1])
    name = ", ".join([lastname, firstnames])

    ID_Subject = " ".join(String[0:2])
    money = String[2]

    print "%s,%s    %s    %s" % (lastname,firstnames,ID_Subject,money)

printFormat(String) 

while x < len(lecturer):
    lecturer_salary.append(int(lecturer [x][2]))
    x = x + 1 

print ""

try:  
    fname = input("Enter filename within " ": ")

    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split()
            printFormat(line) 
            line = line.split()
            lecturer.append(line)         

except IOError as e :
    print("Problem opening file")

print ""
print ""



answer = raw_input("Would you like to display the details of lectureers     from a particular department please enter YES or NO: ")

if answer == "YES" :
    print ""
    department = raw_input("Please enter the department: ")
    print ""

    while x < len(lecturer) :

        for line in lecturer:

            if lecturer[x][1] == department:
                a = lecturer[x]
                a = ' '.join(a)
                printFormat(a)

            x = x + 1




**elif answer == "NO" :
    print ""
    answer2 = raw_input ("Would you like to know all the lecturers within a particular salary range: ")

    print ""

    if answer2 ==  "YES":

        lower_bound = int(input("Please enter the lower bound of the salary range: "))
        upper_bound = int(input("Please enter the upper bound of the salary range: "))

        print ""

        while x < len(lecturer) :

            for line in lecturer_salary:

                if lower_bound < lecturer_salary[x] < upper_bound :

                    print lecturer_salary[x]

                x = x + 1**


else:
    print ""
    print "Please enter a valid input"
```

Comment: What is the format of the file?  Is `-` included? Please be more specific.

Comment: You could also put it all into a Pandas dataframe and then select it with Pandas syntax and no for loop at all see the Pandas (Python library) doc http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: The format of the file does not include the "-" and it is a requirement that I use the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have an array of lecturer and one of lecturer salary. the

```
for line in lecturer_salary:
```

is not needed - just the while followed by the if. Note that this will only print out the salary, not the lecturer details. Since x is the index to both arrays you can access lecturer[x] for the rest. In truth you don't need the lecturer_salary at all, just walk through lecturer and check:

```
while x < len(lecturer) :
    if lower_bound < lecturer[x][2] < upper_bound :
        a = lecturer[x]
        a = ' '.join(a)
        printFormat(a)
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: Python's array and list are not the same. In this case, it's a list.

Comment: A python list is sequential and numerically indexable. While it is more common to use it as an iterable (for/in), it can also be accessed by index like any array. In your sample you were doing both, one inside the other - so that the outer while loop was not doing anything as it is only reached the second time once x is larger than the length of the list.

Comment: That's true. But there is also a separate array module in Python that deals with fixed type members http://pymotw.com/2/array/ so it can be  easily confused.

Comment: THere are also arrays in the numpy - or the matlab module. Arrays can be sequential memory or linked lists. Using an iterator works best for all types, while accessing by index would be slower for linked lists - but only significantly for very large lists. All arrays and most list types can be accessed by numerical index.

Comment: I inputted the code that you suggested but it didn't work. The code is still not printing anything

Comment: add "print lower_bound, lecturer[x][2], upper bound" after the while and before the if. See what is coming out.

Comment: You may need to change the if to "if int(lower_bount) < int(lecturer[x][2]) < int(upper_bound)

Comment: Does Python allow ranged if's? You could also try "if lower_bound < lecturer[x][2] and lecturer[x][2] < upper_bound:"

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you shouldn't name your variable with a capital letter like `String` or `Id_Subject`.

It is simpler to break code into functions and try using a dictionary or class to improve readability and extensibility.

Here is a minimal code using class:

```
lecturers = [] # To store Lecturer instances, which isn't necessary                                                                                     

class Lecturer():
    def __init__(self, id, subject, salary, name):
        self.id      = id
        self.subject = subject
        self.salary  = salary
        self.name    = name

def readfile(filename):
   """read each line in a file and yield a list of fields"""
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            # return a list of fields                                                                                             
            yield line.replace("\n", "").split()

def new_lecturer(detail):
    """Return a new lecturer instance from a list of fields"""
    return Lecturer(detail[0],
                    detail[1],
                    detail[2],
                    {"firstname": detail[3],
                     "lastname": detail[4]
                    })

def print_lecturer_detail(lecturer):
    """Accept a lecturer instance and print out information"""
    print "{0},{1} {2} {3}".format(lecturer.name["lastname"],
                                   lecturer.name["firstname"],
                                   lecturer.id,
                                   lecturer.salary)

def main():
    """This is where all the main user interaction should be"""
    fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
    for lecturer in (readfile(fname)):
        lecturers.append(new_lecturer(lecturer))
    print ""

    answer = raw_input("Would you like to display lecturers by department(Y/N)?: ")

    if answer == "Y":
    print ""
        department = raw_input("Please enter the department: ")
        print ""

        for lecturer in lecturers:
            if lecturer.subject == department:
                print_lecturer_detail(lecturer)

    elif answer == "N":
        # implement salary code here                                                                                              
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This may be an overkill now, but it's better than dealing with lists in a long run. You'll see that dealing with properties become much simpler. You may want to improve each function further and make it more modular and reusable.

@Paul Morrington has the straight answer on the `while` part.

Comment: It is giving me this error message : SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function

Comment: Check if you indent `yield` inside `for`.

Comment: yes Ive indented yield inside for and have still got the same error message

Comment: I then tried to indent the with and then the for and then yeild but that also produces an error message saying unexpected indent and then points to with

Comment: I suspect you forgot `:` after `def readfile()`. It's an indentation error. Maybe you should try pasting your code in an editor with proper indentation help and make them all spaces.